# Are Foward Swept Wings for a Rear Propeller Airplane Feasible?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airfoil, efficiency

**Would going with a forward swept wing design, with the same cord and length of the "A Wing", bring more air the the propeller and tail to increase range, power, or stability?**

Consider the material available today to save additional weight needed to add torsional strength for this wing.

The 1970s, BD-5A can get 1200 miles on the original (A Wing) airfoil/wings. It is known for being unforgiving, stalling often on landings. The airfoil has had some design changes to make it more stable using the "B Wing" at the cost of 1/4th of the mileage. The wings are interchangeable in 15 minutes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The air doesn't flow along the wing quite like that. An airplane with a pusher prop wouldn't know the difference. Plus significant forward sweep requires a lot of extra torsional stiffness, hence weight. And you only do sweep in the first place for transonic performance. You just don't see swept wings more than a few degrees in subsonic a/c. So there's really no point.

Comment: @JohnK Consider the material available today to save additional weight needed to add torsional strength for this wing. Would you say there would be zero benefits?

Comment: For subsonic there isn't really any point in sweep. Airliners have sweep b/c they are transonic.